# How to bring corresponding data in the column

Tags: sql

How to bring the corresponding data in new columns by comparing there other attributes. here in the below table we have 2 weeks of data along with Store ID and Price type, if the price type is "Regular" then we have to add "Reduced" price with same criteria (Year, Week, StoreID) in the new column and if the price type is "Reduced" then we have to add "Regular" price with same criteria (Year, Week, StoreID) in the new column.

| Year | Week | StoreID | PriceType | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10 | S | Regular | 200 |
| 2021 | 10 | S | Reduced | 150 |
| 2021 | 10 | D | Regular | 180 |
| 2021 | 10 | D | Reduced | 120 |
| 2021 | 9 | S | Regular | 35 |
| 2021 | 9 | D | Reduced | 40 |

Has to be change like the below table, in the below output table, "Reduced/Regular" value is 150 in row number 1 because 150 is the corresponding value for 200 with criteria (2021, 10, S) and in 2nd row the Reduced/Regular value is 200 because 200 is the corresponding vale for 150 with criteria (2021, 10, S).
But last 2 rows for week 9 will gives 0 because we don't have corresponding criteria.

| Year | Week | StoreID | PriceType | Price | Reduced/Regular |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10 | S | Regular | 200 | 150 |
| 2021 | 10 | S | Reduced | 150 | 200 |
| 2021 | 10 | D | Regular | 180 | 120 |
| 2021 | 10 | D | Reduced | 120 | 180 |
| 2021 | 9 | S | Regular | 35 | 0 |
| 2021 | 9 | D | Reduced | 40 | 0 |

Kindly help with this logic Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when priceType = 'Regular'
             then max(case when priceType = 'Reduced' then price end) over (partition by year, week, storeId)
             else max(case when priceType = 'Regular' then price end) over (partition by year, week, storeId)
        end) as other_price
from t;
```

Happily, this is standard SQL and will work in any database.